# Homebrew gives SSL error (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) on home network

Tags: networking, home-networking, ssl, homebrew

As the title says, when I try to install packages via homebrew through my home network, I get the following error:

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to akamai.bintray.com:443 
Error: Failed to download resource "rclone"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/rclone-1.38.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
```

However, I can download from the .tar.gz URL that is specified just fine through my browser.

I know this is only a problem with my home network because when I tether my phone it works fine.

Probably got something to do with my router settings and/or ISP but I am not sure where to look.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same issue and it is also limited to my home network.

Comment: Nope, I just use another network for this stuff :(

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding `--ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` to the curl request. Another solution is to download a newer version curl.

Comment: Thanks man, how did you figure it out? Also can you tell me which curl version you installed to get it working, because I got the latest version and its still not working :( I'm on Mac OSX

Comment: @AlexanderEkdahl do you why this happens by any chance? I am curious

Comment: For me this was problem with the office VPN, disconnected and worked fine

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using `LibreSSL`, try re-installing `curl` with `OpenSSL` instead of *Secure Transport*.

The latest `brew`, it [depends on OpenSSL by default](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/0bfb0391d7c2db964a2da4d31a2495d91361df8a#diff-a7a59ba41131628f779debf43858c613), so you've to reinstall it:

```
brew reinstall curl
```

For older Brew, there was an option `--with-openssl` which was [removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510), e.g.

```
brew reinstall curl --with-openssl
```

Here are few other suggestions:

- Run `brew options curl` to display [install options specific to formula](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#options-options-formula).
- Compile from the source. Check [`curl.rb` formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/curl.rb) for more details.
- Make sure you're not using `http_proxy`/`https_proxy`.
- Use `-v` to `curl` for more verbose output.
- Try using BSD `curl` at `/usr/bin/curl`, run `which -a curl` to list them all.
- Make sure you haven't accidentally blocked `curl` in your firewall (such as *Little Snitch*).
- Alternatively use `wget`.

Comment: `brew reinstall curl --with-openssl` get Error: invalid option: --with-openssl

Comment: Check `brew options curl` to display install options specific to formula, as per [manual](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my `brew options curl` gives empty result. What gives?

Comment: It seems the option was [removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510), try reinstalling it without any option. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `brew reinstall curl`, but got: curl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

How do I uninstall it from macOS first (seems macOS builtin include that package).

Comment: Try: `brew uninstall curl`. The one which comes from macOS, you can't uninstall it. You need to install new one in `/usr/local` and Brew should adjust `$PATH`, to point to the new one first.

Answer (score 6):

A thought occurs to me -- have you checked your router to see if it is doing a transparent proxy for you?

If it is, then you may want to turn that off.

If you can't turn it off, then you might want to install a VPN solution that will allow you to bypass it.

Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks. By the router acting as a transparent proxy, I guess it means all my requests are intercepted by the router? Is this a security risk even if my traffic is https encrypted?

Answer (score 6):

For those who are still struggling to resolve this.

Please try:

```
brew update-reset
brew update # This might not be needed.
```

I found this gem [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3410#issuecomment-343922422).

Comment: it work for me.

Comment: me too, I tried a thousand of other  solutions but only update-reset do the magic!